# Express JS MognoDB allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

Today I've got that error message int he console twice, and only could solve it restarting the backend. I'm using Node/expressjs for backend and reactjs for frontend. The backend is serving two websites (for admin and for clients), may it cause such kind of error? or I just have to buy premium cluster on mongodb? Maybe just there's no free space there anymore. Please help me making out how to solve it. Thank you!
<--- Last few GCs --->

```
[9860:000001FB55904120]  6734212 ms: Scavenge 23.8 (28.2) -> 23.1 (29.2) MB, 2.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure
[9860:000001FB55904120]  6734237 ms: Scavenge 23.8 (28.2) -> 23.2 (29.2) MB, 4.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure
[9860:000001FB55904120]  6734552 ms: Scavenge 24.1 (28.2) -> 23.4 (29.2) MB, 6.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF60314052F napi_wrap+109311
 2: 00007FF6030E5256 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33302
 3: 00007FF6030E6026 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF6039B163E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6039964BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF60384094C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF603848E9F v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2559
 8: 00007FF60383DA61 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
 9: 00007FF60383BC65 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1317
10: 00007FF60385C057 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+183
11: 00007FF60358C0B1 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
12: 00007FF603A39FED v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+463949
13: 00000343072A216B
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the request before the error occured:

```
POST /api/8547685765867gurhgfbgjbfgngbgjhtiu5895785hefjsfsfGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG847389jnem/admin/articlesaweek - - ms - -
```

It's router:

```
router.post("/" + process.env.HASHFORADMIN +"/admin/articlesaweek", async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await adminactions.articlesInAWeek(req, res))
})
```

It's the controller's function

```
articlesInAWeek : async (req, res) => {
    const data =  [ (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay()
            )}})).length, (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 1
            )}})).length, (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 2
            )}})).length, (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 3
            )}})).length, 
            (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 4
            )}})).length,
            (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 5
            )}})).length,
            (await Article.find({date: { $gt: new Date((new Date( )).getFullYear(),
              new Date().getMonth(),
              new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 6
            )}})).length
            ];
            return data;
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because of that you called multiple find queries
each query get records and hold in Heap Memory.
its exceed a heap size
so change the queries to following then u can get only count of documents instead of load all documents to heap

```
articlesInAWeek: async (req, res) => {
    const data = [(await Article.countDocuments({ date: { $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date(Date.now()).getDay()) } })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 1
            )
        }
    })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 2
            )
        }
    })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 3
            )
        }
    })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 4
            )
        }
    })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 5
            )
        }
    })),
    (await Article.countDocuments({
        date: {
            $gt: new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(),
                new Date(Date.now()).getDay() - 6
            )
        }
    }))
    ];
    return data;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a strict standard limit for memory usage in V8. you can only use up to 1.7 GB. though you can try.

`node yourScript.js --max-old-space-size=8192`

also after looking at your code. instead of loading the documents into the memory and finding the length. try using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) or [count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)